# PHP + Html tables displaying correctly info

Tags: php, html-table

I'm currently trying to show some categories which come from database into tables. But I want the categories to be displayed this way:

```
    Animals        |   Other    |   Other    --> reached end of DIV, 
    Restaurants    |   Other    |   Other    --> the info must continue in another
    Houses         |   Other    |   Other    --> line
------------------------------------------------------
    Other          |
    Other          |
```

So my logic is to have variables to count `$rows & $cols`..but this won't work for every screen sizes..so I need a better approach.

The following code is just an example of the logic.

```
$categories = $all_categories();

$rows = 0;
$cols = 0;

$output = "<div><table>";

for($i = 0; $i <= count($categories) - 1; $i++){
    $output .= "<tr><td>" . $categories[$i]['name'] . "</td></tr>";
}

$output .= "</table></div>";

echo $output;
```

Is it possible to the table to detect that it has no more space and continue the `<td>` in next line?
Here's also the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G3fUw/

Edit: **Solved**, just needed to change this two lines.

```
<tr style='display: inline-block'>
<td style='display: inline-block'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `td` has `display:inline-block` property so, it will never break when you reach end of `DIV`. so you can use `display:block` property for `td`,`tr` and `table`, or you can use `DIV` with `float:left` instead of `table`.